# GoJS: Prevent specific region from being occupied by nodes in a ForceDirectedLayout

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'd like to have a specific coordinate area reserved for a legend in my GoJS diagram which is using a [`ForceDirectedLayout`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html) for node layouts.  However, the legend shape doesn't affect the layout of nodes when applied as a [`Part`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html), and using a placeholder [`Node`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html) unfortunately doesn't allow placement based on [document coordinates](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/viewport.html#DocumentAndViewCoordinates).  This leads to the legend content overlapping node content depending on how the forces are randomly applied.

How can you create a region in a `ForceDirectedLayout` which affects/applies forces to nodes as they're being calculated but in turn either isn't a node or is a node with a fixed position and no links?

Ideally it'd be possible to define a specific [`Rect`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Rect.html) in the diagram which isn't accessible for nodes, or have a `Part` which can apply forces.
The closest I could find to defining a specific rect is the total bounding box via the layout's [`boundsComputation`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Layout.html) which would just narrow the area and not allow for cutting a specific region out.

Here's a specific illustration of the challenge, where the legend will generally overlap node content since there's no force to repel the nodes:

[image: General sketch of problem]

It appears it may be possible with `ForceDirectedLayout.isFixed` based on the following, but it's unclear how one would go about setting a specific node position on that basis:
https://forum.nwoods.com/t/maintain-existing-graph-shape-when-appending-items/7159/6

Answer (score 0):

You could try a variation of this class:

```
class FixedForceDirectedLayout extends go.ForceDirectedLayout {
  isFixed(v) {
    return v.node.category === "Fixed";
  }
  electricalCharge(v) {
    return (v.node.category === "Fixed") ? 300 : this.defaultElectricalCharge;
  }
}
```

You may want to fiddle with the value returned by the **electricalCharge** method.

To install, just set **Diagram.layout** to an instance of this custom **ForceDirectedLayout** class.

```
const myDiagram =
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    {
      layout: new FixedForceDirectedLayout(),
      . . .
```

Now where you want there to be an empty area, put a node of category "Fixed" covering that area.  For example,

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Fixed",
  $(go.Node,
    { background: "whitesmoke" },  // just for demo purposes, so you can see it
    new go.Binding("position", "bounds", b => go.Rect.parse(b).position),
    new go.Binding("desiredSize", "bounds", b => go.Rect.parse(b).size)
  ));
```

Example model data:

```
myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
  [
    { category: "Fixed", bounds: "20 20 100 100" },
    . . .
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this actually results in that particular node being set to the coordinates defined on your `Rect`.  For instance, with your example the node isn't actually placed at `20,20` but rather moves throughout the space depending on other forces (though the size works).  Is the `isFixed` layout method actually working correctly?